# How to reset the zoom to 100% via keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, app.diagrams.net

I have a fairly big draw.io diagram. I need to move and zoom around a lot. After navigating within the diagram, I would like to reset the zoom to 100%. However, I haven't found a way to do that reliably, because often as not, using the mouse wheel will have it jump from 85% to 105% or 110% and back down again. The "100%" entry in the view menu does not have a keyboard shortcut associated with it.

Is it possible to define that?

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

It will open up a dialog window that'll let you type in the zoom % like so

[image]

Comment: I had hoped for something that is a "one-hit" solution. There is also the "reset view" on Enter, but I haven't found a way to tell draw.io where to go - it keeps going to the wrong location.

Comment: Also just to clarify, even if they're identical, are you on the desktop client or web?

Comment: I am on web - the desktop client seems to be limited to like 30 or 60 fps.